# Помоните исправить код

Tags: php, javascript

Есть скрипт обновления страницы каждые 2 секунды

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function runMultiple()
    {
         $.ajax({
          url: 'create/index/news.dat', // ваш файл
          success: function(data) {
              $("#content").html(data); // блок, который обновляем
          }
        });
    }
    var timerMulti = window.setInterval("runMultiple();", 2000); // 2000 миллисекунд
</script>
   
<div id='content' />
```

но в файле create/index/news.dat есть много include'ов и они не отображаються на странице

Comment: Если ваш JavaScript-код не работает как ожидается, то **всегда и только всегда** первым делом нужно смотреть что пишется в консоль ... В вашем случае это: `Uncaught ReferenceError: runMultiple is not defined`; так как: `window.setInterval("runMultiple();", 2000);`. Советую прочитать какой-нибудь учебник перед тем как начинать программировать (практика без теории — метод научного тыка); например, Learn.JavaScript.Ru.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript их видит просто как строки. Вам надо сделать news в формате php тогда ваши все include будут работать.

Comment: не помогло(((((

Comment: а то что в файле news.dat/news.php инклуды в формате .dat игрет роль??

Comment: попробовал изменить инклуды в файле news.dat/news.php на расшырение .php не помогло(